Stabillity of hitting pool ball aligned in a straight line
While playing pool, my friend showed me this YouTube short video (link). It shows that we can always hit the last ball.
With curiosity, I wonder if it has a stability to compensate for small perturbations or errors of aiming angle and ball placement misalignment.
This is my first attempt by assuming small angle.

Also check with geometry from CAD (Onshape sketch).

I think we clearly see that there is no such stability in this phenomena.
So my calculation does not match the experiment. What could be wrong?

is this system really stable?

if that so, what could make the system stable?


Note: I also tried this myself, as low skill player I still succeed to do this all the time.

That was an interesting video.

I still not sure that this is hallucination of stabillity or it actually a thing...

This is not a full answer. You can obtain a regime of stability even in the idealised model. However, the regime of stability obtained does not explain the videos. For simplicity, I will assume the all the balls to be of diameter $1$, spaced a distance $D$ apart (measured from their centres), all perfectly aligned. I will look at the effect of the misalignment of the initial ball. Let $\theta_n$ be the angle of the velocity of the $n$-th ball with the reference line of balls. You control $\theta_0$, and if you are skilful, $\theta_0$ is small.
You can compute the next $\theta_n$ by induction. An application of the law of sines gives:
$$
\theta_{n+1} = \theta_n-\arcsin(D\sin\theta_n)
$$
You will notice that $\theta_{n+1}$ is well defined iff $|\theta_n|\leq \Theta := \arcsin D$. This simply means that you must not miss the next ball. You can now study linear stability around zero:
$$
\delta\theta_{n+1} = (1-D)\delta\theta_n
$$
Notice that $D>1$ since the balls are hard. You therefore have linear stability iff $D<2$, i.e. as long as you cannot fit a ball between two consecutive ones, you have linear stability. This is therefore not applicable in the video, as the balls are a lot more spaced out.
The model is so simple that you can even study the system globally. For $D<\sqrt2$, no matter the starting angle, you will converge to $0$. For $\sqrt2\leq D<2$, $0$ has a finite basin of attraction, with the critical angle being:
$$
\theta_c = \arccos(D/2)
$$
Thus, the basin of attraction shrinks to zero as $D\to 2$. At this critical angle, you have a repelling 2-periodic trajectory, i.e. the balls shoot out alternatively between two symmetric directions. For $|\theta_0|>\theta_c$, you get out of bound in a finite steps, i.e. you miss the next one after a finite number of collisions. For $D>2$ you always go out of bounds in a finite number of steps.
In the video, you are always in the regime $D>2$ so you never have any stability. However,  even if $0$ is unstable, for $D$ close to $2$ (like in the final setup of the video), the growth rate is very small, so it could be reasonable to be sufficiently skilled to maintain the growth in check for a finite number of balls.

Your experience of successfully trying it yourself suggests that there is a stabilizing influence involved. Clearly though, the simple elastic 'hockey-puck' model you use in your analysis is unstable. Presumably, the discrepancy lies betweeen the approximations of the model and the reality of the actual dynamics involved in the 'experiment'.
As a first guess, I would suggest that inelastic collisions and/or the influence of rotation of the balls combined with friction (both ball-table and ball-ball friction) may make the difference.
